# Sonata admin bundle preview image from some entity in list mapper without sonata media bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I was wondering how should i approach this problem. In sonata admin dashboard i have users and i would like to preview users profile pictures in thumbnails of a ListMapper. I'm new to symfony and still a bit confused trying to wrap my head around these concepts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to create a custom template where you display the image of your user, i will assume that your Entity User as a Picture Entity which has a path method that gives the image URL :

picture.html.twig

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}
{% block field %}
<div>
    {% if object.picture != null %}
    <img src="{{ object.picture.path }}">
    {% else %}
    <span>No picture</span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

You know have to use this template in your list

```
class UserAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->add('picture', null, array(
                'template' => 'ApplicationSonataAdminBundle:User:picture.html.twig'
            ));
    }
}
```

Documentation is available here : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/list_field_definition.html#custom-template

Comment: I don't know why this isn't set as the correct answer. Thanks! One thing to note is the !== does not seem to work. Change it to just !=

Comment: Glad that I helped at least someone else :).
I edited my answer, I mixed twig and php, should use the function "same as" to check the type : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/sameas.html

Answer (score 1):

one separated entity, -no user-, where I have added one media, this for me worked

in admin configureListFields
->add('media', 'string', array('template' => 'SonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:list_image.html.twig'))