# Show the number of rows on a connected table in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have a *user* table, and a list in Sonata Admin.

Also, I have a *file* table, where the users are connected to the files with a *user_id* field.

Now, this is the config for the list of the users. So far so good, it works.

```
// Fields to be shown on lists
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('username')
        ->addIdentifier('email')
        ->addIdentifier('firstName')
        ->addIdentifier('lastName')
    ;
}
```

Tried to find it in the documentation, but it's unclear to me how do I add a field to the list, where the number of connected *files* are indicated, or even better, if there is at least one uploaded file for the user, I have a flag about it in the list in a separate field.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a custom template where you display the information you want :

list_files.html.twig

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}
{% block field %}
<div>
    {{ object.files|length }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

call it in your list method

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('username')
        ->addIdentifier('email')
        ->addIdentifier('firstName')
        ->addIdentifier('lastName')
        ->add('picture', null, array(
                'template' => 'ApplicationSonataAdminBundle:User:list_files.html.twig'
        ));
    ;
}
```

You might need to adapt the template path.

Read this for more details : [Sonata admin bundle preview image from some entity in list mapper without sonata media bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361347/sonata-admin-bundle-preview-image-from-some-entity-in-list-mapper-without-sonata/28381786#28381786)

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you!